# is it possible to make an Excel drop down list with word used as a term by Excel.?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I would like to make a drop down list based on a cell that contains true or false

What I would like to do is if the cell value is true (cell T1) I would like to show a list and if the cell value is false I would like to show another cell value

I'm pretty aware that true and false cannot be used as a cell name So I cannot apply the indirect function

How can I approach this issue ?

Thank you so much

Comment: It looks like you have a good question but it's unclear. Please explain how you would use the indirect function with another cell name. Also describe your worksheet and what you're trying to do.

Comment: @User15 This is exactly what I'm looking for : how to use the indirect function with another cell name , as I cannot use it with a True/False cell name , all I need to do in my worksheet is Whenever the cell value in (Z1) Is true I want to show the list called SecurityUS, else if the value of cell in Z1 is false , I want to show the list of SecurityNOTUS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution I could suggest would be to use the condition on the validation range - and not on the cell in question.

For example if you had TRUE/FALSE in A1 you could use:

```
=IF($A$1=TRUE,"A","B")
```

For each of the intended conditions.

If you didn't want a different list value, you could use #N/A or blank, or could point to another cell reference

Then you just point the data validation list function at that range. It will change as the condition changes

Comment: you have no idea how much I can thank you ! Much appreciated !

Comment: I have one single last question , what if I want to add an else if condition if I want something like : =IF($A$1=Designer,show list A , else if ($A$1=Approval,show list "B")

Comment: Yeah, its nice and simple to do that however, The Excel If function doesn't have an elseif clause:

As such, you need to do a second if in the first If's else clause - something like:

=IF(A1="Designer","List A option",IF(A1="Approval","List B option","No match at all option"))

Comment: OH so I can write both condition seperatly in the data validation source , I see thanks again !! THANKS A LOT !